# running apex sample code making use of input from a java connector

Tags: apex, soap-api, omnichannel

I am talking about the [emp connector](https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector/blob/master/src/main/java/com/salesforce/emp/connector/example/LoginExample.java) here created for listening to a pushtopic. After getting the needed data from the pushtopic, I am supposed to create a record of a class using the apex sample code in [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/omnichannel_external_routing_create_agentwork.htm)

I find it odd that apex sample code is provided instead of java. It appears more straight forward to create the record as part of the java connector which gets the data needed from the pushtopic. How am I suppose to run the apex sample code provided? What should I do with the data received from the push topic? I am thinking of creating a visual force page to include the apex sample code but then I need to send the data to the visual force stored in salesforce's server. This does not look straightforward to me. Can anyone enlighten me on how to do the creating of the record with data from the pushtopic in the most straighforward way ? I am also wondering whether I can ignore the apex code provided and create the record with SOQL query send from the Java connector.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use SOQL to create, update, or delete records (SOQL stands for the Salesforce Object Query Language). To actually perform DML, you could use [WSC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_wsc.htm) for WSDL-based operations, or [HttpClient/JSON](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_httpclient.htm) for REST-based operations. You can also make it intentionally harder on yourself and just download a [WSDL](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_wsdl.htm&type=5) and directly import it.

No matter how you get there, once you've gotten all of your imports correct, the Java way will feel very familiar compared to the Apex code. It might even look like:

```
AgentWork work = new AgentWork();
work.ServiceChannelId = "<ServiceChannelId>";
work.WorkItemId = "<WorkItemId>";
work.UserId = "<UserId>";
work.PendingServiceRoutingId = "<PendingServiceRoutingId>";
connection.insert(work);
```

After all, Apex was designed to look very much like Java, so it'd be easier to port code (at least some kinds) to Apex without too much effort.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/amolsable009/5f12c7da9dc706c1c401) that someone wrote that demonstrates inserting an Account in Java, so you can get more of a feel what it might look like as a full application.

Comment: This is great help. Thanks a lot